# Play code only sometimes in python

Tags: python, selenium

So I am coding a script (for this question I will provide the example using an automatic youtube subscription script) and I was wondering it if is possible to skip lines of code sometimes. I know you can do break/pass/continue but thats if you code it in. I want to be able to skip some code at random. 
Let me provide some code to explain better of what I mean:

```
lines = open('youtube_links.txt').read().splitlines()
random_links =random.choice(lines)

browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1]) 
browser.get(random_links)
time.sleep(4)

browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#subscribe-button paper-button").click()   #randomly hit the subscribe button only sometimes
```

So what this script does is that it chooses a random link from a external text file (a link to a youtube video) and then it goes to it.

What I want to be able to do: So I still want it to pick a random link and go to it. However I want to only sometimes hit the subscribe button. So lets say I play this script 5 times. The first time it subscribes. The second and third, times it doesn't subscribe. Then the forth and fifth time it plays it does subscribe. Is this possible? Any input/suggestions are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Skipping lines is easy enough to do with an if statement, you just need to decide under what conditions you want to skip. For instance if you want to skip it randomly use: if random.randint(0,1):

Comment: Sorry, but what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will randomly subscribe. You may want a more sophisticated algorithm.

```
lines = open('youtube_links.txt').read().splitlines()
random_links =random.choice(lines)

browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1]) 
browser.get(random_links)
time.sleep(4)

if random.randint(0,1):
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#subscribe-button paper-button").click()   
    #randomly hit the subscribe button only sometimes
```